# Is there a way to make Mapbox popups resizable?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I would like to make the Mapbox popup resizable so if the user clicks and drags on the corner/side, they can make the popup bigger or smaller and the content automatically adjusts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality for that provided by Mapbox GL JS. However, you have full control over the HTML element used, so you can implement this feature yourself.